# How to find time intersection between two times stored in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

The problem I'm facing is not very complicated and there are several answers to this here, but I didn't see any which is solving the problem as I need.
So I have a table with two fields of type VARCHAR, named timefrom and timeto.
Those fields store time in this format: 12:00, 05:18,00:05 .... I have no date and no seconds, just hour and minutes in 24/h time format.
I have a form with two fields, starttime and endtime. And now I want to select all rows from database where the user starttime and endtime intersects with the timefrom and timeto fields in DB. 
I have the following query:

```
"SELECT * FROM reservation WHERE ((timeto>='$timefrom' AND timeto<='$timeto') OR (timefrom>='$timefrom' AND timefrom <='$timeto'))"
```

This query works for all kind of intersections but not if the time given by user fits in the time stored in DB. 
For example if DB timefrom=20:00 and timeto=23:00 and the user input starttime=21:00 and endtime=22:00 the query doesn't return any intersection and it should. 
It would be a great help if anyone could show me a reliable solution. THANKS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saving any sort of date/time as a simple string is not a good idea because you lose out-of-box features for working with dates & time provided by MySQL itself.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM reservations
WHERE
TIME_FORMAT(timefrom, '%H:%i') >= '21:00' AND TIME_FORMAT(timeto, '%H:%i') <= '23:00'
```

Comment: my bad, i didn't test it. this one works (updated the answer)

Comment: Ok, thanks it's working now but there is still a problem which is not solved by this query. If my starttime is 19:00 and my endtime is 21:00 (which means that my endtime equals to the starttime stored in db) than the the query returns the row, but it shouldn't because there is no intersection.I think it's because all the <= and >= operators in the query. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: I guess that you should then just do `SELECT * FROM reservations
WHERE
TIME_FORMAT(timefrom, '%H:%i') >= '21:00' AND TIME_FORMAT(timeto, '%H:%i') <= '23:00'` and validate that end > start before performing the query. If you need to accept params like "between 23:00 and 2:00AM", then you need a bit more work before running the query in order to get proper results.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just check that either one of the user input starttime or user input endtime is in between the time limits. And whether DB starttime and endtime are both between user starttime and endtime. That would mean an intersection.

```
SELECT * FROM reservation WHERE ('$timefrom' BETWEEN timeto AND timefrom) OR ('$timeto' BETWEEN timeto AND timefrom) OR ('$timefrom' <= timefrom AND '$timeto' >= timeto)
```

Comment: Anf if $timefrom less and $timeto more than (timeto, timefrom) interval ?

Comment: My bad, i missed that one. Thanks I will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

Well you could just add a third check if the user-Time is between the `timeto` and `timefrom`:

```
OR (timefrom <= '$timefrom' AND timeto >='$timeto')
```

This would spit you out the rows with the times in between too.

MySQL provides an `intersect` filter too. Look at [this](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/intersect.php).
There you can provde the rows to look at and then say that you just want to select the rows which provides an intersection with your values.

Comment: The INTERSECT filter is for checking values in two or more tables and not against variables.